# Communication between non-parent-child components

Tags: angular, components, communication

I just want to do some experiment. So when I click a button of a A component, some function of a B component should invoke. But I don't know how to do that if these components are not parent child to each other. Can you please help me

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 2):

When there is **no child-parent** relationship between components

You should create a service having a `Subject` and inject this service in both of these components.

**some.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
   public testSubject = new Subject<string>();
}
```

**comp-a.component.ts**

```
export class CompAComponent {
    constructor(private someService: SomeService) {
    }

    btnClickHandler() {
       this.someService.testSubject.next('clicked');
    }
}
```

**comp-b.component.ts**

```
export class CompBComponent {

    constructor(private someService: SomeService) {
       this.someService.testSubject.subscribe(next => { this.someFunction(data);});
    }

    someFunction(msg) {
       console.log(msg);
    }
}
```